# How to use the LinReg command on the TI-89?

Tags: statistics, calculator, linear-regression, ti-basic

When I try to use the LinReg command, it works, but just says Done

```
LinReg c1,c2        Done
```

I know how to do it with the CALC button in the Data/Matrix editor, but don't understand how it works as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

One only needs to use

```
ShowStats
```

and hit enter and it will show you the regression stuff.